# Добавления елементов в массив и сохранения

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

И так у наc есть массив  Arr по нажатию на кнопку значения с инпута доб. в массив.Но после перезагрузки страницы массив пуст , как сделать запоминания елементов в масиве или как реализовать(без базы и сервера)!

```js
var Arr = [];
$('button').click(function(){
  var imp = $('input').val();
  Arr.push(imp);
  console.log(Arr);
});
 console.log(Arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Номеp" id="Number">
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запускаете ваш скрипт в браузере то [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCollArray'))
$('button').click(function(){
  var imp = $('input').val();
  arr.push(imp);
  localStorage.setItem('myCollArray', JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Arr is null - возникает проблема!

Comment: когда в `localStorage` нет данных то вам придет `null` поэтому нужно добавить проверку на null `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCollArray')) || []`